# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, sdl

I've been trying to learn SDL, but haven't been successful at linking the .lib

When compiling my C++ program I'm told the file cannot be opened.

```
Build started 8/8/2014 1:08:01 AM.
     1>Project "C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KinectTest\KinectTest\KinectTest.vcxproj" on node 2 (Build target(s)).
     1>Link:
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KinectTest\Debug\KinectTest.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\lib\x86" /LIBPATH:"C:\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86" Kinect10.lib SDL.lib SDLmain.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KinectTest\Debug\KinectTest.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KinectTest\Debug\KinectTest.lib" /MACHINE:X86 Debug\KinectTest.res
         Debug\KinectTest.obj
     1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL.lib'
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KinectTest\KinectTest\KinectTest.vcxproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.22
```

Directory Contents:

```
 Directory of c:\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86

03/15/2014  07:34 PM    <DIR>          .
03/15/2014  07:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/15/2014  07:33 PM         1,007,104 SDL2.dll
03/01/2014  11:23 AM           116,400 SDL2.lib
03/01/2014  11:23 AM            40,536 SDL2main.lib
03/01/2014  11:23 AM           821,670 SDL2test.lib
               4 File(s)      1,985,710 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  69,829,705,728 bytes free
```

As you can see above the directory of the lib was included and the file is in fact in that location

Props File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\SDL2-2.0.3\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>SDL.lib;SDLmain.lib;opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to link the library calling it `SDL.lib` when in fact it should be `SDL2.lib`

In the directory:

```
03/01/2014  11:23 AM           116,400 SDL2.lib
```

From Additional Dependencies:

```
<AdditionalDependencies>SDL.lib;...</AdditionalDependencies>
```

This is the same for `SDLmain.lib` which should be `SDL2main.lib`

Comment: Seemed to be one of those nights. Didn't post this question until after 45 minutes of trying to figure it out.... Thanks!